# Java do-while loop isn't working

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I want my program to keep asking the question until it gets a response it can use, specifically a number from 0 to 20. I have a lot of other stuff on this class, so here is a small excerpt where the do-while is (I have named the variables and all that for everything).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    do {
        halp = 1;
        System.out.println("What level is your fort?");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        try { 
            fortLevel = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()); 
        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){System.out.println("Numbers only, 0-20"); halp = 0;
    }

    if(halp < 1) {
        work = false;
    }

    if(halp > 1) {
        work = true;
    }

    while(work = false);
}
```

Comment: is there any reason to create the scanner inside of the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an assignment in your `while` expression:

```
while(work = false);
```

You can replace with

```
while(work == false);
```

or better

```
while(!work);
```

---

If variables `halp` and `work` are not used anywhere else, they could be eliminated giving you:

```
do {
   System.out.println("What level is your fort?");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
   try {
    fortLevel = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
   } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
     System.out.println("Numbers only, 0-20");
   }

} while (fortLevel < 0 || fortLevel > 20);
```

Comment: i've done this, but it still types out the "numbers only, 0-20" and then doesn't allow me to retype sc

Comment: You are setting `halp` to `1` which makes `work` `true` so you exit the loop immediately.

Answer (score 4):

```
while(work = false); // here you are assigning false to work
```

should be

```
while(work == false); //here you are checking if work is equal to false
```

- `=` an assignment operator used to assign value
- `==` an equality operator used to check if two operands have same value.

As work is boolean you could even just use this:

```
while(!work)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this:

```
if(!work) {break;}
```